# how to update single column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

flight_seats table:

```
FlightId DepartureDate                 SeatNo class     fare    status         Source  Destination      Arrival Date
sh120   03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    1   A   900 confirmed   pew karachi           03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
sh120   03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    2   A   900 open            pew      karachi          03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
sh120   03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    3   A   900 confirmed   pew karachi           03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
sh120   03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    4   A   900 open            pew  karachi              03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
```

passenger table:

```
pnr  FlightId    DepartureDate                 SeatNo  class     fare      status       Source  Destination      Arrival Date

1     sh120 03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    1   A   900 confirmed   pew karachi     03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
2     sh120 03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    2   A   900 reserved    pew karachi     03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
3     sh120 03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    3   A   900 reserved    pew karachi     03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
4     sh120 03-JAN-16 10.00.00.000000 AM    4   A   900 reserved    pew karachi     03-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000 PM
```

note:i have a select list on status column in passenger table.i want to update a status column in flight_seats for a single seat.when i try my code it will update status for all the seats.i want to update it for a single seat through select list.

- FlightId,DepartureDate,SeatNo are primary key in flight_seats which are referenced to the passenger table as foreign key.

Comment: Whats the primary keys of both tables?

Comment: FlightId,DepartureDate,SeatNo are primary key in flight_seats which are referenced to the passenger table as foreign key.

Comment: How are you updating the passenger table - have you built a tabular form or what?

Comment: Is your select list a LOV - will this be dynamic? Do you include the seat number in your where clauses? e.g. update passenger where Flightid = 'sh120' and SeatNo = '1'?